# Xcode 11.3 - Unable to run on device

Tags: ios, xcode, build, swiftui

I've been working on an app within Xcode that runs fine on the simulator.  I wanted to try it on my device.  However, I've been encountering a frustratingly vague issue every time I try to install/run it on my device. 
The installation fails and the message I get includes:

> Unable to
>   install "AppName" Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit Code: -402620415
>   -- App installation failed Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit Code: -402620415 Failure Reason: An unknown error has occurred.

The target deployment is set to iOS 13.2, the device is an iPhone X running 13.3, and Xcode is version 11.3 running on MacOS 10.15.1.

I've tested other apps on my device previously, though not since updating to iOS 13 and macOS Catalina and Xcode 11.  Any thoughts/guidance are much appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

1. Go to general
2. Delete the app
3. Reboot the phone
4. Make sure you are running the new os version on ios i.e 13.4
5. After reboot connect back your phone
6. Choose the phone on Xcode, Run it

Answer (score 6):

Not really an answer per se.  But I did a [forced restart](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/force-restart-iphone-iph8903c3ee6/ios) to my device (volume up, volume down, hold down wake/sleep/Siri button until Apple logo appears), and then I tried again.  The app appeared to install correctly at that point and run on my device.  So seems like something weird was going on, but I forgot the first rule of tech support: "Did you try power cycling your device?"

Anyway, leaving this here so that if someone else encounters this issue, they too may be reminded that it's worth trying a forced restart.