# Failed to start remote service on device problem in xcode

Tags: xcode, flutter

I create a flutter app and now I'm trying to run it through XCode on my real iPhone, but after the installation finishes, I face the following problem:

[image]

Also with I trying to run the application on my real phone, after clicking on the application icon, I face a white screen appears, and then the application closes directly.

Catalina  10.15.3

IOS 14.2

XCODE 11.7

Also I was make a trust to app in phone

Does anyone know the reason for this problem?

Comment: I have a fix for this I answered here on StackOverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68378023/1890317

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem maybe because of two reasons:

First: Xcode 11.7 doesn't have support files for iOS 14 you can download it from here https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport

Second: I have this problem now and I couldn't fix it.. but I have iPhone with iOS 14.2 and iPad with iOS 14 so the problem was just on the iPhone but after I updated the iPad with iOS 14.2 it happened with it.. so the problem maybe because of the iOS 14.2 so we have to wait for the update or because of the Xcode 11 version and we have to download the Xcode 12 version..

I hope we can find a solution quickly...

Comment: This worked for me when I updated to sdk 14.0, but not for 14.4.2 anymore. XCode 11.7 (not beta)

Answer (score 1):

make sure to have the latest system update on your target device and the latest Xcode version as well. The error should disappear.
Best,
Ralf

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by using the above solution but it has happened again. So, I have followed these instructions and fixed again:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61665031/6586109

Answer (score 0):

A good first place to look is **Window > Devices & Simulators** in xCode, then find the details for your device. There may be error information here that helps you find the fault.

---

Restarting devices and installing updates seem to fix this problem for a lot of people.

For me, there was a red notice in the device window about connection to the device and it turned out to be the **cable** that was at fault.

This was an official Apple cable, just a few months old, and still works fine for charging and data transfer; and I've been using it with xCode without problems for a couple of months. It seems to be possible for Apple cables to develop some tiny physical fault that seemingly only xCode is sensitive to.

Using a different cable worked first time for me.

---

There seem to be a few variations on the exact error message with the same root causes varying depending on exactly what xCode was trying to do at the exact moment it failed: I'm on xCode 12 and for me it was:

> **Failed to start remote service on device**
>
> Failed to start remote service com.apple.installation_proxy on device