# Xcode 12: Failed to start remote service "com.apple.debugserver" on iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, ios14, xcode12

I updated my Xcode to `Version 12.4 (12D4e)` and after that I am unable to run my app on my device
`iPhone X iOS 14.4.2`.

### Its alway show this Error

[image]

### When I check my device connected status, Its show as connected

[image]

### Action I applied

1. Clear `DerivedData` folder.
2. Unpair device and connected again.
3. Drank 20+ coffees.

Comment: I just changed my Lightning Cable, It's sounds crazy, but it's worked for me.

Answer (score 31):

I was able to fix the Xcode 12 app install/deployment issue described above:

```
Failed to start remote service "com.apple.debugserver" on device.

Domain: com.apple.dtdevicekit  
Code: 811
Recovery Suggestion: Please check your connection to your device. 
User Info: {  
  DVTRadarComponentKey = 261622;  
}
...
```

by doing the following steps:

1. Quiting Xcode.
2. Deleting Xcode cache directory (ie, `rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`).
3. Rebooting the offending iOS device.
4. Connecting the iOS device to Xcode by cable (instead of wireless network connection).
5. Starting Xcode again.

By the way, I've a setup very close to yours:

- **Xcode 12.5 (build 12E262)** and
- **iOS 14.5.1** (on a iPhone Xʀ device)

Comment: worked for me (xcode 14.3)

Comment: This worked for me as well, allowing me to add my new iPhone 14+.  Xcode 14.3.1.  Many, many, many thanks!

Answer (score 16):

#### 1st solution

I fixed this by:

1. Closing Xcode
2. Deleting the current iOS version in my folder that's related to my device.

   ```
   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport
   ```
3. Restarting Xcode. Wait a little bit for it to refresh and copy cache files in my case then Run.

Based on [Can I delete data from the iOS DeviceSupport directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930198/can-i-delete-data-from-the-ios-devicesupport-directory) it's ok to delete the iOS DeviceSupport folder.

I noticed when I did it and reconnected my device it re-downloaded the iOS device Support files.
If the support files don't download and the cache files are not copying, try restarting your computer as well.

I started also getting this error:

> Errors were encountered while preparing your device for development.
> Please check the Devices and Simulators Window.

Restart your phone and reconnect it to the compter if this happens. Then you should get a message in Xcode saying:

> Preparing your phone for development.

#### 2nd solution

1. Unpair the device in Xcode.
2. Clean the project.
3. Unplug and then restart iPhone.
4. Restart Xcode.

#### 3rd solution

If none of the above worked, I was able to run the program by re-enabling **Connect via Network**.

After doing this now I can run project via USB.

#### 4th solution

I submitted this bug to Apple. Apple also suggests this can be caused by faulty data cords. Maybe try another cord as well.

Comment: try all the cords and iPad run ok ... just the phone!  And it did download, just you have to click it and does not auto-start if you change your program, unlike iPad

Answer (score 12):

Unplug the iPhone, Turn it off and again turn it on and reconnect. It worked for me. Sometimes iPhone Debug connection network server clogs up. When you restart iPhone it reinitiate the connection.

Comment: Worked for me as well, just normal turn off and on again. No need for any weird workarounds. iPhone 12 Pro on iOS 16.6.1, Xcode 14.3.

Answer (score 3):

This issue keeps happening and it seems like there's a myriad of reasons that may cause it, and so there are a lot of solutions that fixed it for people. Someone even suggested that none of the fixes actually work, and it's only the fact that time passes as we try different solutions that actually fixes it. Nevertheless, I will share what worked for me and what I found so far.

a. In the past, the issue was most often caused for me by using an older version of Xcode with a newer iOS. Apple doesn't always release the version of Xcode that supports the latest iOS at the same time, and this issue sometimes happens as a result of that. There are people who suggest right clicking the Xcode App > Show Package Contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneOS.platform > Device Support and renaming the folder for the latest supported version to the one running on the phone (for example renaming 16.0 to 16.1). I've had better luck with using the Beta of Xcode if it's not out yet (in this case using 14.1 RC2 instead of 14.0.1).

b. Incrementing the build number and setting a Display Name. This seems to have fixed the issue after nothing else worked. Again, this seems very random, so it could be unrelated, but it did fix it in my case after nothing else suggested on all the threads about this worked.

c. Deleting the profile in Settings > General > VPN & Device Management

Other suggestions I've seen across threads:

- Restarting the device (seems to be the most popular solution)
- Unpairing the device
- Checking device status under Window > Devices and Simulators. There may sometimes be some further info about what is going on here, the device may still be preparing for development or downloading symbols or whatever
- Using another cable. This never worked for me, after trying with 3 cables, 2 from Apple and one 3rd party, but others reported it worked
- Deleting Derived Data (use Dev Cleaner or rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Uninstalling the app manually from the device
- Resetting Network Settings
- Force restarting the iPhone

Apple really needs better errors and less ridiculous bugs like this.

Comment: cannot find profile? Where is it under may I ask?

Comment: It is under Settings > General VPN & Device Management now.

Answer (score 2):

I reset the iPhone network settings and it works!

Answer (score 1):

I had to update Xcode to fix this issue because my version of Xcode did not support my up-to-date iOS version.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue and also had the problem that I wasn't able to connect my device by cable (it popped on and of), so I had to use wifi connection on Xcode.

I was able to see the icon of the app created by Xcode on my iOS device, but whenever I tried to start it, it won't do so giving the "Untrusted Developer" error message.

I fixed this by going to:
Settings > General > VPN & Device Management > Developer App

Here you have to chose the App and consent to trusting it.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by,
Following the steps : **Window > Device and Simulator > Select your device** and  **Right Click on it** > **Unpair** after that **re-connect your iOS Device** then boom... Clean builds and run the app, it will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The only working method for me is just to disable and enable developer mode on the iPhone (this will require a reboot). Checked many times!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, my solution is update my ios version(15.1 to 15.2 beta)

---

I tried all the resolvent, nothing worked

- restart iOS, Xcode, macOS
- clear `DeviceSupport`, `Caches`
- unpair iphone, change lighting cable

Then I find my ios version(15.1) does not exist in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`.

I try to fix it, but failed.

Finally, I can only update my iOS device to 15.2 beta version, It solved! Xcode is update to beta version too.

My devices original version:

- iOS 15.1
- Xcode 13.1 (13A1030d)

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Xcode 13.3 and I fixed this by unplugging and plugging the cable between my MacBook Air and my mini iPad 3.

Answer (score 0):

on Xcode 14.3.1, I disconnected and connected the wire back, and then ran it.
Worked!

Answer (score -1):

Upon solutions aren't working for me. Restart my iPhone then all well done.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33760390)